# Remove annotations

Tags: qgis-3, annotation

Is there a way to remove annotations from a QGIS project? Can I navigate to a folder and delete them instead of going into the map canvas and deleting them there?
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're describing. I get the impression you might be coming from a CAD background, if so then GIS treats labelling/annotations very differently. Are you talking about labels on individual features? Can you share a screenshot of what you're describing?

Comment: Here's my screenshot:

Comment: Annotations (as in text labels manually placed on the map canvas with no related feature) are only saved in the QGIS project, so you will have to either delete them manually, or run search and replace on the project file using a text editor.

Comment: Thanks for the information !

Answer (score 10):

A very fast way to remove all the annotations from your project is to use a PyQGIS script in the QGIS python console.

the script is

```py
manager = QgsProject.instance().annotationManager()
for i in manager.annotations():
   manager.removeAnnotation(i)
```

This will remove all the annotations in a single action.

Comment: Looked all over the documentation to delete persistent Annotations added by accident (QGIS 3.26), finally your little Python did the job. THANK you for sharing this !